# Should I create individual properties in a class or just a method to set the values?

Tags: vb.net, class, methods, properties

I am learning vb.net and I am having trouble wrapping my head around the following...

I can create several properties of a custom class and get/set values or I can create a method to set them all at once. If each property is going to allow read and write should I just make a method to assign values all at once? I assume that I am missing a very important piece here. Example:

I can create 2 properties:

```
    Public Class Employee
        Public Property LastName as string
        Get 
            Return strLastName
        End get

        Set(ByVal value as string)
            strLastName= value
        End Set
        End Property

        Public Property FirstName as string
        Get 
            Return strFirstName
        End get

        Set(ByVal value as string)
            strFirstName= value
        End Set
        End Property
    End Class
```

or I can create a method:

```
    Public Class Employee
        Public Sub AddEmployee(ByVal strLastName, ByVal strFirstName)
            LastName = strLastName
            FirstName = strFirstName
        End Sub
    End Class
```

I apologize for such a noob question, but any insight is greatly appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have a single method, you will *have* to use it even if you only want to change the value of a *single* field.

Additionally, in such a method, if you need to validate the input, you will need to write quite a lot of code for validation that is not relevant to all of the fields.

If values *must* be updated together, use a method to update them together and do not provide setters.

The reality of things is that how to do this depends on what you are modelling in your class. There are no hard and fast rules that say that properties are better than methods or vice versa.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I can think of several scenarios now where I would want to use a method over a property and vice versa. I think that a combination of both will be helpful for this particular class I am building. I just need to do what makes sense for what i'm trying to accomplish. Your explanation really helped. Thank you!

Comment: If you decide to use the method, may I suggest you use a different name like SetEmployee or NameEmployee. AddEmployee (to me anyway) suggests that there might be several employees in your class and this function adds a new one. It might not seem like a big deal now but it will greatly improve the code readability and you or other people reading your code will appreciate it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason not to support both properties and a method that sets multiple properties.

Commonly, a constructor is used to create an instance of the class and to set some properties.  In VB, naming a class method "New" defines it as a constructor.  In your example, if you rename your AddEmployeee method to New, you will have a perfectly fine constructor.  Then you program can create new instances as such:

```
Dim emp1 as New Employee("Burdell", "George")
```